# How would I build a Chrome extension to mimic Safari's back/forward page slide animation?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, safari

I'm looking for some general guidelines in developing a Chrome extension to make the entire page slide from left to right when going back a page and from right to left when going forward a page.  This is how most OS X apps work with natural tracking enabled, but Chrome employs a simple arrow to the left or right of every page.  Is this possible to implement given the limitations of the Chrome extension library?

Comment: It may well be possible but I think it would be quite a job! You'd need to capture any webrequest (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) preload the page into a DIV and animate it into view. But then your URi would be wrong, back button usage would be even more of a headache!...Just thinking out aloud here, maybe others can suggest a better solution.

Comment: Yes, this is one thought I had.  But it would be much nicer to capture the buffer already loaded by Chrome to get the exact page placement and DOM state.  Reloading the page would ruin any dynamically loaded elements.

Comment: Yep, as I thought this through I quickly realised the limitations. I don't think there is a way to tap into the buffer in the Chrome API, but I may be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you don't have access to such low level UI stuff in a Chrome extension. You would have to simulate the effect by injecting a content script into all tabs as they load and animate the entire document or body. This would add overhead to every page visited in the browser, but could potentially work.